# org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String,

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I could add new object via postman but I want to add via code
Could you help me please?

> org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String,

Even this Meta question is not clear. I wonder if the title is not your own voice, but an error that you are getting in the Stack Overflow question editor/UI. It sounds like perhaps when you tried to write your question on the main site, there was not enough paragraph (i.e. not code formatted) text. Could you take a screenshot of the error and put it in your question here

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "image_entity")
public class ImageEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String hash;

    @Column
    private int size;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        return hash;
    }

    public void setHash(String hash) {
        this.hash = hash;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Session sessionOne = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        sessionOne.beginTransaction();

        ImageEntity image1 = new ImageEntity();
        String a = null;
        image1.setHash(a);
        image1.setId(10l);
        image1.setSize(100);
        sessionOne.save(image1);

        sessionOne.getTransaction().commit();
        //HibernateUtil.shutdown();
        SpringApplication.run(MasApplication.class, args);
    }

Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String model.ImageEntity.hash] by reflection for persistent property [model.ImageEntity#hash] : model.ImageEntity@4322aef3
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.getForInsert(GetterFieldImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:5170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:611)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:606)
    at MasApplication.main(MasApplication.java:70)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field model.ImageEntity.hash to model.ImageEntity
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:71)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: I could add new object via postman but I want to add via code
Could you help me please?
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.String,

Comment: Show the db table

Comment: alter table image_event owner to postgres;

create table if not exists event
(
 id bigint not null
  constraint event_pk
   primary key,
 source_type char,
 source_id bigint
  constraint event_source_id_fkey
   references image_event
  constraint event_source_id_fkey1
   references video_event
);

Comment: So where is hash in that table...